# 'ModelOptions' object has no attribute 'local_many_to_many'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, authentication, django-nonrel

I'm trying to migrate a Django project into GAE ( Google App Engine )

The problem is I found this error when trying to login:

```
'ModelOptions' object has no attribute 'local_many_to_many'
```

Line provocking the error:

```
user = authenticate(username=uName,password=uPass)
```

Partial Code:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['submit'] == 'Login':
            postDict = request.POST.copy()
            lForm = LoginForm(postDict)
            if (lForm.is_valid()):
                uName = request.POST['username']
                uPass = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(username=uName,password=uPass) 
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request,user)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
                    else:
                        message = 'Account Deactivated'
```

Trace:

```
    ['/Users/xavicolomer/Dropbox/projects/workspace2/test', 
'/Users/xavicolomer/Dropbox/projects/workspace2/test/django.zip', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/antlr3', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/ipaddr', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/simplejson', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/graphy', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', 
'/usr/share/django/django-trunk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']
```

Comment: Some additional detail would be helpful. Please include the full stack trace, the authenticate method definition, and whatever model definition includes local_many_to_many.

Comment: Well looking at this I see to possible future errors, I'm using python2.6 instead of 2.5 and django 0.96 when it was supposed to use 1.2

Comment: As Drew Sears says, additional info will be nice. In the mean time  the advice of Waldemar in this forum could be usefult for you:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/a13117221ab00251

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that the link is at least 2 years old and I am already using Django non-rel project.

Comment: then you should tag it with django non-rel. Your error isn't related to vanilla Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the stock auth app provided with django-nonrel? It won't work because it requires JOINs. Install [django-permission-backend-nonrel](https://bitbucket.org/fhahn/django-permission-backend-nonrel) and things will work fine.